# AutoGen DB models for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am wondering if there's anything out there for ASP.NET that is similar to Django or Ruby on Rails. Specifically, I'm looking for something that allows me to auto-generate the database models by specifying my classes in the controller and what not. Would I be able to achieve those functionality with IronPython or IronRuby?

Comment: FYI, it's "ASP.NET", one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want RoR like environment in ASP.NET, you may want the following combination

1. ASP.Net MVC
2. [Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) with Migration

Here are some useful resources;

http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/05/24/mvc-starter-2
http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/subsonic-using-migrations/
http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/3.0_Migrations
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [ADO.NET Entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) which allows you to [generate model classes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs) from an existing database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the answers from Darin and Soe, and you're in good shape.

For automatically generating your model, you'll want to look into an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

Your question discusses models and controllers, which leads me to believe you want an MVC framework.  In this case, [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/(S(d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45))/mvc) is the way to go.  It works well with EF and Linq to SQL.